# What is the different between Docker plugin and Docker with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-docker

I am little confused regarding Jenkins on docker. I know that those two approaches exist but I don't know  what the difference between them and Which approach to use?

**What is the difference between them ?**

**cons and pros for both approaches?**

Thankfull for your inputs.

Comment: You cannot use the Docker plugin to utilize a `node/agent` in pipeline, so there is no real comparison to be made here for your purposes.

Comment: Exactly: the docker plugin is for building/pushing images and running containers, and not for `node/agent`.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Could you please give a detailed answer for the question, I have edited the  original question. thanks